# How do I convert this ES6 class to a Factory Function?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, factory

I think I understand the importance of [not using ES6 classes](https://github.com/joshburgess/not-awesome-es6-classes), valuing composition over inheritance, and using [factory functions instead of `prototype`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R39zdSLd8ic) (feel free to correct me on any of these statements if you disagree).

My question is how to convert this example using ES6 classes (and ES6 map) to use a factory function.

```
class DefaultMap extends Map {
  get(key, defaultValue) {
    return this.has(key) ? super.get(key) : defaultValue;
  }
}
```

example:

```
const defaultMap = new DefaultMap();
defaultMap.set('foo', 'bar');
console.log(defaultMap.has('foo')); // true
console.log(defaultMap.get('foo')); // bar
console.log(defaultMap.has('baz')); // false
console.log(defaultMap.get('baz', 'qux')); // qux
```

Comment: A factory function wouldn't use the new keyword

Comment: Inheritance seems to be completely appropriate here, since `DefaultMap` *is-a* `Map`.

Comment: actually this is a bad reason to inherit, OP is just adding a simple extension to Map.

Comment: `var factoryFunction = () => new DefaultMap();`? What's the problem with your approach?

Comment: You just need the class construct to subclass built-ins. This isn't proof that factory functions are useless or just a hype. In fact they are awesome in many use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you're doing is adding a function to `Map` then there's nothing wrong with your approach. I'd even argue that it's the preferred way of going about it. But if you really want a factory function instead of inheritance, you could accomplish it like this:

```
function createMap() {
  var map = new Map();
  var oldGet = map.get;
  map.get = function(key, defaultValue) {
    return this.has(key) ? oldGet.call(this, key) : defaultValue;
  };
  return map;
}

const defaultMap = createMap();
...
```

Comment: I just abandoned my answer because the code in it was effectively identical to yours. IMO the OP has allowed himself to be drawn into a religious war that seems somewhat dogmatic. For me, the most pragmatic approach would indeed be using inheritance, but similarly, a quick monkey-patch does the job just as well, and might be considered more idiomatic w.r.t. current JS trends. Horses for courses.

Comment: I definitely feel wrapped up in some holy war and definitely focus much too much on doing things w.r.t current JS trends like you said. I was going to continue to do it the class way but Mike's way also seems better at allowing setting a default value at instantiation.

Comment: @spender Factory functions provide **inheritance** too, except subclassing of built-ins such as map. Factories simply don't depend on constructors and `new`. That's all. No a religious war, nowhere.